# Why do these if-statements in scheme always result to false?

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to build a simple 4 function calculator for class in Scheme and this is what I've come up with. It's a function that takes in three variables. No matter what I try, the if-statements do not work and always turn out false.

I've tried replacing the symbols with strings such as "plus", "minus" etc. but I keep getting the same result.

```
(define calculator
  (lambda (val1 operator val2)
    if (equal? operator +) 
        (+ val1 val2) 
        (if (equal? operator -) 
            (- val1 val2)
            (if (equal? operator *) 
                (* val1 val2)
                (if (equal? operator /) 
                    (/ val1 val2)
                    '())))))

(display (calculator 1 + 2))
```

All of the statements evaluate to false and I get whatever the else-statement is in the last if-statement.

Comment: What Scheme implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses around the first `if` form. It should be like this:

```
(define calculator
  (lambda (val1 operator val2)
    (if (equal? operator +) 
        (+ val1 val2) 
        (if (equal? operator -) 
            (- val1 val2)
            (if (equal? operator *) 
                (* val1 val2)
                (if (equal? operator /) 
                    (/ val1 val2)
                    '()))))))
```

Without it `if` is looked at as a variable, then it will evaluate `(equal? operator +)`, `(+ val1 val2)` the `(if ..)` and then always evaluting `'()` which always will end up as the returned value.

When you have an `if` `elseif` type of confitional it is better to use `cond`:

```
(define calculator
  (lambda (val1 operator val2)
    (cond ((equal? operator +) (+ val1 val2)) 
          ((equal? operator -)  (- val1 val2))
          ((equal? operator *) (* val1 val2))
          ((equal? operator /) (/ val1 val2))
          (else '()))
```

Also know that this can be written:

```
(define (calculator val1 operator val2)
  (operator val1 val2))
```

Comment: You should also be able to use `eq?` instead of `equal?`—might be slightly cheaper.

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf Since the `operator` is a procedure it might not be enough to compare with `eq?`, but `eqv?` is safe from R6RS and later. I left it as is since it was secondary to OPs challenge.

Comment: Good call on both accounts. :) Thanks for teaching me something!